# What is the difference between creating a memory array with a "new" statement and init array with specific values?

Tags: arrays, compiler-errors, compilation, ethereum, solidity

First way to create array via "new" statement:

```
bytes32[] memory var1 = new bytes32[](2);
var1[0] = 0x123....;
var1[1] = 0x234....;
```

Second way:

```
bytes32[2] memory var1 = [0x123...., 0x234....];
```

1. What is difference between this types of initialization?
2. Targetly I try to understand the difference between this ways for solve another problem with "Invalid implicit conversion from bytes32[2] memory to bytes32[] memory requested" when I pass to one of this array to this function
   `function test1(bytes32[] memory myVar)`

Answer (score 0):

### Fixed array

```
// this is called inline initialization
bytes32[2] memory var1 = [0x123...., 0x234....];
```

this is fixed array which has predetermined size. we are initializing array with mentioning the size of array in its type

```
// its type is an array which contains only 2 bytes32 elements
bytes32[2]
```

### Dynamic Array

```
bytes32[] memory var1 = new bytes32[](2)
```

Dynamic arrays have `push` and `length` method but fixed array does not. even though you mentioned its size is 2,later on you can add more items into the array with  `var1.push` method

Dynamic arrays also can be initialized inline

```
bytes32[] memory var1 = [0x123...., 0x234....]
```

the difference is we did not add size to its type

```
// we did not define its size inside [ ]
bytes32[]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
One main thing what I've got from this one - solidity has dynamic and fixed types of array. Before I thought what solidity has only one difference between arrays - it's memory and storage. But in your answer if I understand right you make some mistakes. I've found a lot of things [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/types.html#array-literals)
1) the `.push` member functions are not available for memory array. `.length` available for all arrays
2) `Dynamic arrays also can be initialized inline`-unfortunately no.`It is planned to remove this restriction...`